# Swing: provide a file name to save

Tags: java, swing

I have a `save` button when I click that it will open a dialog and I can choose a location to save the image.

```
            save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                        chooser.showSaveDialog(null);

                        String location = chooser.getSelectedFile().toString();
                        demo.saveImageToLocalDisk(jFrame, location);
                    }
                });
```

Then the whole JFrame will be saved in a certain location of the disk. The code,

```
private void saveImageToLocalDisk(JFrame panel, String location) {

        BufferedImage image = null;

        try {
            image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(panel.bounds());
        } catch (AWTException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Graphics2D graphics2D = image.createGraphics();
        panel.paint(graphics2D);

        try {
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpeg", new File(location + "/Graphics.jpeg"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }
```

I would like to provide the name of the file as well. How do I achieve that?

Comment: The file name is `location + "/Graphics.jpeg"`, no?

Comment: Yes @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Are you asking how to have the JFileChooser allow the user to select a file name?

Comment: The file name is `"/Graphics.jpeg"` currently. I need a way to provide a customized file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you could replace this line:

```
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```

with this one

```
chooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPEG-Datei", "jpeg"));
```

in order to allow .jpeg-files only for the selection and change this line

```
 ImageIO.write(image, "jpeg", new File(location + "/Graphics.jpeg"));
```

to this

```
 ImageIO.write(image, "jpeg", new File(location));
```

Moreover, you need to add

```
if (!location.endsWith(".jpeg")
   location += ".jpeg";
```

before the `ImageIO.write` command in order to add the .jpeg extension if the user does not type it into the dialog.

At the moment, you are only allowing the user to pick a folder, but not a file in the dialog. If you do the changes above, the user can go into the folder he wants to use and type "MyGreatScreenCaptureHaha.jpeg" or leave out the ".jpeg" at the end in the filename textbox of the `JFileChooser` or choose an existing file to overwrite - just like in MS Word.